# Updating value of K in K-Means Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

What is the best way to cluster a dataset with no labels and no idea of the number of clusters required?

For example, using the Iris dataset with no labels or knowledge of the number of label classes.

My idea:

- Compute the mean square distance from each of the existing clusters for a sample
- *If mean square distance > some threshold by a factor that depends (penalizes) on k, then, add that a “new” candidate.
- *If a new cluster was added, find the new “best” k+1 cluster centers
- If no new cluster was added, go to next row

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is plot the elbow curve at different K-values as described [here](https://bl.ocks.org/rpgove/0060ff3b656618e9136b)

Specifically,

> 1) The idea of the elbow method is to run k-means clustering on the dataset for a range of values of k (say, k from 1 to 10 in the examples above), and for each value of k calculate the sum of squared errors (SSE).
>
> 2) Then, plot a line chart of the SSE for each value of k. If the line chart looks like an arm, then the "elbow" on the arm is the value of k that is the best
>
> 3) So our goal is to choose a small value of k that still has a low SSE, and the elbow usually represents where we start to have diminishing returns by increasing k

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with the elbow method, correct me if I am wrong but does it not require labelled data to calculate the SSE? Is this method applicable to unlabeled data and for data in which we do not know the approx number of clusters?

Comment: K-means is an unsupervised algorithm so this should work. You're not computing the SSE from known "optimal" clusters - you're computing the the SSE from the current clusters (which are then iteratively improved)

Comment: To chime in on this excellent answer, @AidanSmyth you ask "but does it not require labelled data": The answer is no, you are applying an _assumed_ label by specifying different k-values. The clustering algorithm assumes there are k labels, and minimizes the in- and out-of-cluster SSE to apply the cluster label to each point. You then repeat this and recalculate for every value of K you care to try. The elbow is the optimal number of classes to assume exist

Answer (score 0):

Dozens of methods have been proposed on how to choose k.

Some variants such as x-means can dynamically adjust k, you only need to give the maximum - and choose the quality criterion AIC or BIC.